# Physiologic basis behind increased survival with double coverage for community acquired pneumonia

Tags: infectious-diseases, antibiotics, pneumonia, streptococcal-infection

Double coverage (generally cephalosporin + macrolide) is currently the recommended treatment for patients hospitalised with community acquired pneumonia (CAP) [[1](https://www.acpjournals.org/doi/10.7326/AITC202204190)]. This seems mainly to be due to better coverage of S. pneumoniae and increases survival in pneumococcal bacteriemia [[2](https://academic.oup.com/cid/article/36/4/389/437900),[3](https://doi.org/10.1345/aph.19174)]. Better coverage of atypical pathogens may play an additional role.

So the question arises: **What is the pathophysiologic basis for the increased survival with double coverage for inpatient CAP?**

A few hypotheses:

1. Synergic activity against S. pneumoniae

- *In vitro* data suggests that macrolides and cephalosporins actually are antagonist against S. pneumoniae [[4](https://doi.org/10.1093/jac/46.6.973)], thus this seems unlikely to be the main cause.

2. Immunomodulation by macrolides

- However, in pneumococcal bacteriemia non-macrolide double coverage also improves mortality according to observational data reported by Baddour et al [[5](https://doi.org/10.1164/rccm.200311-1578OC)].

3. Coverage of resistant S. pneumoniae strains

**Is there are commonly accepted theory for this phenomenon ?**